# How to show complexity of queue/dequeue is O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, queue

I have a homework for algorithms and have following problem:

Given a queue Q and the methods:

`queue(Q, x) //inserts x to the queue from left`,

`dequeue(Q) //returns most right element of Q` and

`multiqueue(Q, k) //runs dequeue(Q) k times`,

How can i show that n operations at the most will need O(n) steps starting with an empty list?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are you stuck on?

Comment: So i came to the conclusion that queue() and dequeue() have a complexity of O(1). Multiqueue() has a complexity of O(k), which is also a constant complexity. If i now start with an empty list i can fill it with n operations and can dequeue it n times. Which would be n * O(1) + n * O(1) = O(n). If i now use dequeue k times i would add O(k) to O(n) which would still result in O(n), right? That´s my approach till now.

Comment: It has to be a  amortized analysis i think but it doesn´t say in the exercise explicitly.

Comment: `k` isn't constant, it just can't be more than the number of elements in the list (which is why "starting with an empty list" is there) (I assume `dequeue` should be **removes and** returns, otherwise this doesn't work).

Comment: @dukeling yes you are correct. It removes the element.

Comment: Queue is an abstract data type (adt), you need to state the implementation before you can address the complexities. The O(1) in the comments suggests a linked-list under the covers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see from your comment you almost answered your question.

- queue is O(1) as you explained
- dequeue is O(1) as you explained

What is tricky is that multidequeue(Q, k)  defined with k smaller then the number of elements in the queue.

We assume the queue starts empty that's why you can assume that multi dequeue called always for complexity of  O(n)  and I'll explain :

If you call multidequeue n times it means you didn't use the other operations include **queue** that's why you won't have any elements to dequeue hence your  k is a real constant.

Assuming you call **queue** n-1 times you can call multidequeue only once because you spent all you other n - 1 operations already.

That's why O(num_of_times_calling_multidequeue * multidequeue)  = O(n)

Answer (score 0):

As @gefen keinan pointed out i solved it like this:

Suppose we have an empty Queue Q and n available operations.
 We know that queue() and dequeue() both have O(1) complexity. The "worst case" is having n - 1 times the operation queue() and then have multidequeue(k) with the parameter k being n - 1, because if we use it more often it will just return an error.

With this knowledge we can come to the conclusion of having (n-1)*O(1) + (n - 1) * O(n) = O(2n) = O(n).

Thank you all for you answers.